# enable/disable airplane mode using adb command on kotlin language

Tags: android, kotlin, dart, adb, airplane-mode

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
```

It works if done through the adb program. But if you try to execute in your program, nothing happens. Root are present on the phone, also when the function is executed, a toast pops up stating that superuser rights have been granted.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'settings put global airplane_mode_on 1'");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true'");
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable the Airplane mode,use the following adb commands:

*adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS*

#toggle/opposite

adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 23

Comment: If I wrote the code correctly, then your method does not work.
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent 19 & input keyevent 19 & input keyevent 23");`